# editing V4.master page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, branding

I'm trying to edit and get rid of a few spaces in between the bar and a custom banner done by me, but when I cut this part of it drops me an error. How can I get rid of this table without it dropping me an error..? or how can I edit it properly

```
<table class="s4-titletable" cellspacing="0" style="height: 0.5px">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="s4-titletext">
                                    <h1 name="onetidProjectPropertyTitle">                                          
                                    </h1>
                                    <span id="onetidPageTitleSeparator" class="s4-nothome s4-bcsep s4-titlesep">
                                    <SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow runat="server"/> </span>
                                    <h2>
                                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" />
                                    </h2>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: You might draw more attention if you make your title into a proper question.  The current title, "editing V4.master page" isn't descriptive of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just use CSS as you cannot remove the contentplaceholder. You can use this property:

```
#myTableObject {
visibility: collapse;
}
```

This will remove a row or column, but it does not affect your table's layout. The space taken up by the row or column will be available for other content.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the table doesn't generate an error, what will throw an error is removing the ContentPlaceHolder that's referenced since SharePoint will try to use it. You can restructure the markup around that placeholder any way you'd like, but you cannot remove it.

If you don't want it visible, you can wrap an invisible div or something around it, but the placeholder has to be physically present on the page.

Comment: @John FYI, do not modify the existing V4.master - instead make a copy and modify and apply as custom masterpage!